# XeLaTeX and svg - Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode

Tags: xetex, babel, warnings, svg, xecjk

I am using XeLaTex to compile the following LaTeX-code:

```
\documentclass[]{book}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}  % main language
\usepackage{xeCJK}  % for Japanese fonts (requires XeLaTeX)
\setCJKmainfont{IPAMincho} 

\usepackage{svg}  % causes the warning

\begin{document}

\includesvg[width=7cm]{example-image}  % tried different svg-files

This is text in UKenglish. 
これは日本語のテキストです。

\end{document}
```

with [example-image.svg](https://we.tl/t-obXAT0EMlU) and resulting in the following output:

> [image: result of compiled LaTeX-code]

I also obtain the warning "**Package transparent Warning: Loading aborted, because pdfTeX is not running in PDF mode.**"

How do I get rid of that warning?

What I tried so far:

- Other compilers. They work with `\usepackage{svg}`. But, they do not support `\usepackage{xeCJK}`, which I would like to use in order to just write Japanese characters whenever I like to in the document without having to put it into special brackets or similar.
- svg-image to another format. I have a lot of svg-images to include and do not want to change them into other formats - to have a really good quality pdf in the end. The texts in the images should also be the same font as the text in the document.

Comment: well the transparent package doesn't work with xelatex. If you don't need transparency use `\usepackage[notransparent]{svg} `, if you need transparency you can try at the begin of your document (before \documentclass) `\DocumentMetadata{}` . This will load the extended pdf management. Japanese should also work with lualatex.

Comment: `\usepackage[notransparent]{svg}` does indeed work for my case. Thank you! 
`\DocumentMetadata{}` works as well for my case, but I have not tried for transparency.
The `xeCJK`package does not work with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: I know that xeCJK doesn't work, but depending on your use case they are other solutions (e.g. luatexja).

Comment: `luatexja` works for me as well, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing @Ulrike Fischer's answers

XeLaTex (2 options):

1. Use `\usepackage[notransparent]{svg}` in above's markup if transparency is not needed.
2. Write `\DocumentMetadata{}` at the beginning of the
   begin of the markup before `\documentclass`.

LuaLaTex:

3. Use `\usepackage{luatexja}` instead of `\usepackage{xeCJK}` `\setCJKmainfont{IPAMincho}` in above's markup.